# Onclick with If else with javaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener {
    let hour = new Date().getHours();
    if (hour < 20) {
      greeting = "Good day";
    } else {
      greeting = "Good evening";
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<button id="clicker" onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

How do I get this function to work correctly ? Needs to show the greeting

Comment: Please include some more detail in your question. How does it not function correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick="myFunction()"` adds the event listener. When you click, it calls `myFunction()`, but all this does is add another event listener, it doesn't set the greeting.

The next time you click, it will call `myFunction()` again, which adds another event listener. This time the event listener that was added during the previous call to `myFunction()` will also be executed.

The third time you click, it will add a third event listener, then the previous 2 event listeners will also be executed. So every time you click, you execute the previous N event listeners, and add another one.

You shouldn't use both `onclick` and `addEventListener()` in that function -- just use one or the other.

Also, just setting the `greeting` variable doesn't display anything. You should assign to an HTML element so you see it.

Your syntax of the `addEventListener()` call was also totally wrong. You're missing the event name, the `function()` keyword, and the parentheses around the arguments. You should have been getting a syntax error in the console, unless this was just a copying error.

```js
document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let hour = new Date().getHours();
  if (hour < 20) {
    greeting = "Good day";
  } else {
    greeting = "Good evening";
  }
  document.getElementById("message").innerText = greeting;
});
```

```html
<button id="clicker">Click</button>
<div id="message"></div>
```